# I install my application from memory card. It replaces my another app

Tags: android

I have developed two apps for Android.
I copy them to memory card of my LG P500 via USB.
I use `AppsInstaller` for that.
First app installation is okay.
I see it's icon and can run it.

Installation of the second app replaces the first.
I don't see the icon of my second app in Android.
I only see the icon of the first app. 
But touching it runs the second app.

First app has icons in appropriate project folder as

```
res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
```

I use `myApp2.png` for icons in second project folder.

Nevertheless 2-nd replaces the 1-st app.
What's wrong in my project?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using same package name in both application

Comment: restart your phone, then the icon will be changed

Comment: Yes. The package name is the same. But is was creating during creation of Android project.

Comment: package name should be unique for different android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your *Package Name* is same for both of the application, So just change the PackageName.

Comment: Thanks. I will change it. But I see it is not easy. It seems I have to create the project from scratch again.

Comment: nopes, you can do it easily. Refactor your packagename by right clicking on src's package and also change the packagename in ManifestFile.

Comment: I did refactor of the package name. I tryed to run on emulator. I got the following error in IntelliJ IDEA:DDM dispatch reg wait timeout
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 52454151: no handler defined
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 48454c4f: no handler defined
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
Can't dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined